# uwp crashes after several sqlite table inserts

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I develop a UWP app and I insert 5 rows per second in a SQLite table.
When the index of the table  reaches 2000 the applications crashes.( exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).)

Any ideas why and how can i fix this?

```
 using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename = TTsqlite.db"))
            {
                db.Open();

                SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
                insertCommand.Connection = db;

                //Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks
                insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@Entry,@Entry2);";
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entry", tb.Text);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entry2", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                try
                {
                    insertCommand.ExecuteReader();

                }
                catch (SqliteException error)
                {
                    //Handle error
                    return;
                }

                db.Close();
```

Comment: what is the exception when the app crashes?

Comment: there is no exception...The program '[6588] SQLiteTTest.exe' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409). this is what is displayed

Comment: Well, your catch block is swallowing up any exception that might be occurring.  Can you check the Application Log in the Windows Event Viewer to see if there is more information?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! i found the solution. It was very simple. Beacaus i call this function in a timer that ticks every 80 milisecond, after several loops the connection tried to close when it was already closed, so that conflict made the app to crash.  The only code i put was an extra if statement tha checked whether the connection was closed in order to open it again.

Comment: Try using async methods.

Comment: @ThomasBikias You could make your solution as an answer.